# How to use JavaScript search on the same page while the user is still typing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a JavaScript search for a `div` within the same page. I'm currently using this code to display my search query:

```
$('.form-search').on('submit',function(){return false;});
$('.form-search .btn').on('click', function(e){
    var query = $.trim($(this).prevAll('.search-query').val()).toLowerCase();
    $('div.staff-container .bold').each(function(){
         var $this = $(this);
         if($this.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query) === -1)
             $this.closest('div.staff-container').fadeOut();
        else $this.closest('div.staff-container').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Here's a demo of an example with HTML and CSS:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vq4q9ygn/)

So I want to display the `div`, while the user is still typing. I know there is a refresh function, but I just cannot understand JavaScript. I'm a newbie student.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a bit of refactoring you can both handle the click on the Search button and updating the search results as you type on the text input. This should work:

```
function updateResults() {
    var query = $.trim($('.search-query').val()).toLowerCase();
    $('div.staff-container .bold').each(function(){
         var $this = $(this);
         if($this.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query) === -1)
             $this.closest('div.staff-container').fadeOut();
        else $this.closest('div.staff-container').fadeIn();
    });
}

$('.form-search').on('submit',function(){return false;});
$('.form-search .btn').on('click', updateResults);
$('.search-query').on('input', updateResults);
```

Updated Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1w8L0oeq/

Answer (score 1):

Is that you want ?
You just have to listen 'input' event instead of click.

`$('.form-search .search-query').on('input', function(e){ ... });`

http://jsfiddle.net/817tfr03/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyup() function on the searchfield as a trigger, instead of click().

Similar to what is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39791406/5897779)